# Recurring donations at iATS are processing twice

Tags: recurring-contributions, iatspayments

This week our recurring donations started process 2 times about 10 minutes apart. It is only recorded in Civi 1 time. The logs in Civi and Drupal only show the first time, there is nothing there for the second time.

iATS however, has 2 charges. Is this an iATS issue or do I need to look for something on our end?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that our webhost was transferring servers and they had our Civi instance running on both the old and the new servers. Once they shut down one, problem solved. Thanks to KarinG and Alan Dixon for helping us find where to look.